# Como crear un proxy usando yew

Tags: proxy, rust

Tengo una aplicación frontend funcionando en yew de rust funcionando en la ruta localhost:8080, y otra backend en actix-web que funciona en la ruta localhost:8000, la pregunta es, ¿como puedo crear un proxy para que se pueda acceder al backend a través de la ruta localhost:8080/api?

Answer (score 0):

Bueno después de un rato investigando encontré el siguiente [link](https://trunkrs.dev/configuration/#proxy). Y a la verdad la solución es bastante sencilla, solamente hay que agregar el archivo Trunk.toml con la siguiente configuración que para mi caso es:

```
[[proxy]]
rewrite = "/api"
backend = "http://localhost:8000"
```